# Alternatives to `FragmentTabHost`?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-tabhost

What I am trying to do is create a layout of the below structure:

```
-------------------------
|       Constant        |
|     LinearLayout      |  
|                       |
-------------------------
|          |            |
|   Tab1   |   Tab2     |
|          |            |
-------------------------
|                       |
|   Fragment's layout   |  
|     which switches    |
|     on tab click      |  
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
-------------------------
```

However, as mentioned in many other SO questions (all of which have no answer as far as I know), the Fragment overlaps with the tabs, rather than stays under them. I've looked for an answer and have tried several ways to resolve this, but nothing works for all layout resolutions (ie: I don't want to set a definite height to the tabs).

So I'm wondering, what would be the most appropriate alternative to `FragmentTabHost` that can give me the desired layout?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: Try the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564085/android-fragmenttabhost

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the toplayout in your drawing to be the place where your Appname or something is, or menus, there is already the Actionbar to do that. You dont need a Linearlayout.

Incase you really want to have a own layout there that is NOT the Actionbar, for whatever reason that may be, im not really sure there is something like that that works flawlessly. Maybe better just to build a own type of Tabnavigation with buttons?

Anyway, a working layout that doesnt have the effect of fragments inside tabs is here:

Fragment.xml & Fragment 2 & Fragment 3 (exchange to the correct names)

```
public  class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.win_lang_dailyuse, container, false);


    return view;
}
```

}

Tablistener.xml

```
public  class MyTabListener  implements ActionBar.TabListener {
Fragment fragment;


public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}


public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // nothing done here
}
```

}

MainActivity.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2, tab3;
Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_test);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Home");
    tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Calculator");
    tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Notebook");

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab1));
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab2));
    tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab3));

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
}
```

Now fill the 3 Fragment XML-files with whatever Layout you want.

Comment: I'm not looking to use the actionbar tabs specifically because I need to have a constant `linearlayout` that contains a couple `EditText`s.