# Android FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tabhost

I've already implemented FragmentTabHost, but my Fragments are going outside the tabhost.
Here is my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                PlaceholderFragment.class,null);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts")
                .setIndicator("Contacts"), PlaceholderFragment2.class, null);
    }
}
```

And here is my fragment:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment2 extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
    />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

And fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is that the fragment goes outside it's tab.
Here's the photo
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your activity_main.xml to

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

and your activity's onCreate to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            PlaceholderFragment.class,null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts")
            .setIndicator("Contacts"), PlaceholderFragment2.class, null);

}
```

Although I strongly suggestion *not* using a tabhost at all. I would instead go for something [in the lines of this solution](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter).